# Which Bitcoin-related services are certified secure by external parties?

Tags: security, services, websites

There are a number of Bitcoin-related websites that offer services related to handling sensitive user information (like eWallets holding onto our private keys), but not many of them are certified by a reliable third party to be secure.

For example, MtGox is [certified by Norton](https://trustsealinfo.verisign.com/splash?form_file=fdf/splash.fdf&dn=mtgox.com&lang=en) to be free of malware and analysed for security flaws on regular basis.

What other Bitcoin-related services are certified secure by external parties?

Comment: These certifications are totally bogus and mean nothing. They do simple port scanning and that's about it.

Comment: Especially if you don't define what a "reliable" third party is.

Comment: Don't trust a 3rd party to hold your wallet. Run the Satoshi client on your machine and learn to secure your wallet yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked my mom (whom I know to be reliable) and she agreed that my service, bitvau.lt, was indeed entirely secure and functional. She also said she was proud of me and that she didn't think I'd ever earn anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

CampBX contracts with McAfee to run a scan:

- https://www.mcafeesecure.com/RatingVerify?ref=campbx.com